# New Line in Mail

Tags: python, django, email, newline

The django-function for sending a mail (see bellow) works perfectly fine!

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail

send_mail(
    'Subject here',
    'Here is the message.',
    'from@example.com',
    ['to@example.com'],
    fail_silently=False,
)
```

Unfortunately there are no informations about creating new lines inside the message text! Does anyone know the solution or has the same problem? What's the best way to include these?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `\n` for a new line.

Comment: Could you provide an example? When I add \n the email still arrives as a single test string with %0A in place of the \n. Thank you,